# view with incremental dates

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgres table `Prop` with columns

```
date date,
ins1 integer,
insamt1 numeric,
ins2 integer,
insamt2 numeric,
ins3 integer,
insamt3 numeric
ins4 integer,
insamt4 numeric
```

ins1, ins2.... represent number of months and insamt1, insamt2...represent amount. This table is a legacy data table imported from dbf. So I have to work with this structure.

One sample row from the table:

```
'2017-03-15', 2, 12000.00, 3, 10000.00, 1, 14000.00, 4, 8000
```

Can a view be made like:

```
   date      amount
'2017-04-15' 12000
'2017-05-15' 12000
'2017-06-15' 10000
'2017-07-15' 10000
'2017-08-15' 10000
'2017-09-15' 14000
```

....

or should I construct a new table and insert data via script.
Using **Postgres 9.4**

**EDIT:** The amounts get due from the clients of the company where the clients agree to pay every month.

Comment: What is the logic for the transformation?  It is not obious.

Comment: edited the question to explain the logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a lateral join for this  I am thinking:

```
select date + ins * interval '1 month', insamt
from t cross join lateral
     (values (ins1, insamt1),
             (ins2, insamt2),
             (ins3, insamt3),
             (ins4, insamt4)
     ) v(ins, insamt);
```

EDIT:

Oh, I think I get it:

```
select date + gs.i * interval '1 month',
       v.insamt
from t cross join lateral
     generate_series(1, ins1 + ins2 + ins3 + ins4) gs(i) cross join lateral
     (values (1, ins1, insamt1),
             (ins1 + 1, ins1 + ins2, insamt2),
             (ins1 + ins2 + 1, ins1 + ins2 + ins3, insamt3),
             (ins1 + ins2 + ins3 + 1, ins1 + ins2 + ins3 + ins4, insamt4)
     ) v(s, e, insamt)
where gs.i between v.s and v.e;
```

Comment: error function gs does not exist...and some explanation will be a lot of help. Thanks

Comment: @shh . . . That was a typo.  It is fixed.

Comment: I have just started to understand the solution....deserve more upvotes, sadly cannot give more than one.